# Is VLAN a requirement to configure VxLAN?

Tags: networking, switch, vlan

I'm reading about VxLAN and its benefits, one thing that is not clear to me, and have not read anywhere is if VLAN is a MUST for VxLAN or are both independent and can work without one another.

Example I need connectivity between 2 sites, do I have to 1st configure VLAN, then configure VxLAN atop or can I configure VxLAN without VLAN.

I read about VxLAN in detail on [SDXCentral](https://www.sdxcentral.com/data-center/definitions/enterprise-data-center-networking/) and [Juniper's](https://www.juniper.net/us/en/research-topics/what-is-vxlan.html#:%7E:text=VXLAN%20is%20an%20encapsulation%20protocol,the%20use%20of%20virtual%20networks)  website as well.

SDXCentral article says

> As was referenced before, a VXLAN is based on VLAN technology. A VXLAN has subnets that require tags for routers and switches to keep the traffic within a subnet and to apply the established rules for that subnet. VXLAN tagging can also be used when sending traffic between an organization’s data centers over a long haul connection.

and again in Takeways

> VXLANs use VLAN tagging systems and layer 2 network addressing to segment traffic and keep networking devices from knowing what data packets contain.

Juniper's website says

> VXLAN is a technology that allows you to segment your networks (as VLANs do)

From both I understand VxLAN can work in conjunction with VLAN but does not necessarily require VLAN and can work independently if the router or switch supports VxLAN, yet I cannot ascertain if this is true.

Can anyone clarify this.

Comment: VxLAN has its own encapsulation that is different from VLAN encapsulation. Doc isn't that difficult to find: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7348#section-5 /

Comment: Thanks, I believe my question is misunderstood, my question is if I need to have VLAN 1st setup in order to configure VXLAN ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is VLAN a requirement to configure VxLAN?

Not technically, but practically.

VXLAN is used to tunnel a VLAN trunk over IP/UDP. In theory, you could have VLANs inside the VXLAN tunnel only, but in practice you'd use the same VLANs on normal switch ports as well (tagged or untagged).

In order to set up a VXLAN tunnel you only need a single VLAN which is always present on an appropriate switch.

If you don't need/want VLANs at all you might want to check out another tunneling protocol like L2TP or PPTP.

However, if your two sites are separated by the Internet you'll want to use encryption at all times which VXLAN doesn't provide. You should consider IPsec and *route* your connections instead of trying to switch them. VXLAN is a technology for L2 connectivity across distributed data centers, *not* intended for the open, hostile and less reliable Internet.